# Python 3 IDE for teaching

Tags: python, python-3.x, ide

With Python 3 maturing and slowly gaining adoption, we're taking the plunge and adopting it in our introductory programming classes for kids aged 12-18. Is there a *free* (preferably open source) IDE you'd recommend that supports Python 3, preferably meeting the following criteria in order of necessity:

1. Cross platform (Windows and Linux)
2. Standard features: syntax highlighting, auto-indent, etc.
3. Run button, rather than console where you have to type "python foo.py".
4. Context-sensitive help (e.g. when they hover over `math.floor()` it should give help for the function).
5. Embedded Python shell.
6. Built-in debugger
7. Useless crud stripped, e.g. they don't need refactoring tools during an intro class and auto-completion gets in the way of teaching. Along the same lines, it should be lightweight as some kids will go home to old PCs unable to run beefy IDEs such as Eclipse.

Comment: @Chris Preferably cross platform (Windows and Linux), but if Windows-only is a winner I'll take it.

Comment: The free Komodo Edit (scaled down open source version of Komodo IDE) comes closes although there's no built-in python debugger (paying version only). Don't know a perfect fit for your needs but the following might be interesting if you haven't seen it yet: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonEditors

Comment: @Chris Komodo Edit doesn't support Python 3, afaik.

Comment: Is one of your critera that it should be free? If not then Wing IDE and the full Komodo are both good fits (I think the recent Komodo 6 has proper Python 3 support but haven't tried it yet).

Comment: @Scott Yes, it must be free. We've tried Wing 101 in two courses (free) and that was rather unstable and kept crashing. It was also terrible at handling things like infinite loops, giving no feedback which is terrible when teaching.

Comment: What kind of feedback is it supposed to give for an infinite loop?

Comment: @Falmarri An indication that it's running, at least. It buffers the output so you don't even know anything happened at all.

Comment: Komodo 6 is really good. But might be a bit complicated to people who can't even handle IDLE. I still think IDLE is the best for teaching purpose.

Comment: @Kabie IDLE is categorically out due. We've tried it twice, it was terrible.

Comment: Komodo 6 does add Python 3 support. I find it simpler than IDLE because of the windowing...

Comment: Also checkout eric5 IDE.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) meets most of your requirements (as others mentioned in the comments) and supports Python 3 from version 6:

- **Open source and free.**
- *Cross platform (Windows and Linux, also Mac)* ― built on [XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XULRunner).
- *Standard features: syntax highlighting, auto-indent, etc.* ― Komodo has the best Python auto-completion I've seen; they'll do automatic type inference from variable assignments.
- <kbd>Run</kbd> *button, rather than console where you have to type "python foo.py".* ― [Can be simply added](http://morlockhq.blogspot.com/2008/01/launching-python-shell-and-running-code.html).
- *Context-aware help* ― supported when you press <kbd>(</kbd> plus it will do this nicely on objects that have been instantiated from other classes.
- *Embedded Python shell* ― The full Python shell integration is only in the commercial IDE, but you can easily hook up a shell into a command output window by adding a toolbox recipe for `python -i`.
- *Built-in debugger* ― Unfortunately not (but neither do lots of the light-weight IDEs recommended above) ― this is only in the commercial Komodo IDE. I'd recommend using [Winpdb](http://winpdb.org/) alongside Komodo Edit for development ― it's faster than the Komodo IDE debugger (and lots of other debuggers) in my experience. Whether this'll fly with high school students would be the question.
- *Useless crud stripped* ― Komodo's clearly got more stuff in it that IDLE so it depends how you see this. Auto-completion can be turned off.
- *Lightweight for kids who go home to old PCs unable to run beefy IDEs such as Eclipse* ― This may also be a downfall ― I'd say Komodo is less beefy than Eclipse though.

Extra things to consider:

- Komodo is great at web development: it supports nice syntax highlighting and code completion on embedded CSS inside HTML etc…
- Support for [extensions](http://community.activestate.com/addons) (along the same lines as Firefox, plus the extensions can be written in Python) ― this could be useful if you need some tweaks to the UI etc for the courses.

Comment: I'm going with this one because for now I believe it's the best option given our circumstances. However, I'm also going to have a close look at Eclipse+PyDev and PyCharm if we can work out a licensing deal with them.

Comment: @marcog: you can apply for becoming an education partner to get free licenses from ActiveState too. http://www.activestate.com/partners/education-partners (see my answer below)

Comment: @Sridhar Ratnakumar Discounted rate for students is $100. That's too much for the majority of our target audience, unfortunately.

Comment: Note that Komodo Edit is Linux/Windows/Mac cross platform, not just Linux/Windows. (even though Windows/Linux were the only ones required, this is still a benefit).

Comment: Now that the world has changed, I would look at one of the free PyCharm versions...

Answer (score 11):

Eclipse + pydev can do that. It's free. UI isn't very simple, but you have debugger, highlight, shell and completion.

**UPD:** Here is [sample screenshot](http://dev.collabshot.com/show/b472ac/). It's pretty simple imo.
12-18 is more like teenager, not a kid, I'm sure that they fluent with much more complicated interfaces like facebook :)

Comment: and its very popular for other languages.

Comment: That's a heavy-duty IDE for a lightweight task. I hope the 5th graders have at least 4GB of RAM.

Comment: Why don't use well-tweaked IDE? It fairly simple to get used to it and after all you'll have all big-IDE features. I don't think, that these teenagers retarded and can't get it.

Comment: As Rafe says, too heavy-duty and completely misses the point on criteria #6.

Comment: Not downvoting, but I agree with Rafe Kettler. Eclipse and pydev is a killer combo but it doesn't really fit the description marcog gave...

Comment: +1 to Rafe Kettler's comment. Eclipse is way too big for the job.

Comment: To add, many kids will be under-privileged and go home to computers that could never run eclipse.

Comment: @Rafe: You don't need 4gb of ram to run eclipse... Why would you not teach on an IDE/platform that the students will be using afterwards...

Comment: @Falmarri because the students are in middle school and high school, and it's an intro to programming. Most of them won't be going on to program enterprise Java apps.

Comment: s/too big/kind of too big/. Teaching programing while not teaching about programming tools (well, when they don't need more than 1 hour of explanation.. Eclipse fits) is, imho, bad. Programming is also about tools and I believe there's nothing wrong with accepting this overhead of "OK, today's lesson will be about the Eclipse IDE and Pydev". I'm not saying it's One True Approach, but it's certainly not an approach to be frowned upon.

Comment: @Kos Given the constraints we're working with, that just doesn't work. We have 20 hours to introduce programming.

Comment: @marcog, you don't need to teach them eclipse in-depth. Just make pre-configured distributive and teach how to create new file and push "big play button". That's it, not harder than IDLE.

Comment: @Andrew Hmm, that *might* actually work if we strip all the bloat.

Comment: @Rafe: Stop spreading FUD; since when has Eclipse become "enterprise development only" IDE? I don't have a problem with you complaining about its performance but this is ridiculous...

Comment: @SanjayTSharma it's not FUD, I never said that Eclipse is enterprise only, I just don't think a giant IDE like Eclipse would be remotely suitable for middle schoolers.

Comment: @Rafe: Why not? Yeah it's feature rich, but why would you want to strip all the features? So there will be a lot of things they won't use, so what? It's probably the easiest IDE to use by far, you click run and it runs. If this was C++, I'd say yeah, CDT is pretty confusing. But pydev is literally click to run

Comment: @Falmarrri: actually, Pydev is pretty confusing as far as Python IDEs go. It's more like "click, choose from 3 options, then run."

Comment: @Falmarri Because these are kids that have never programmed before. Programming is already a new, complex thing to them. Why add more unnecessary complexities in the form of a complex IDE?

Comment: @marcog: Because you can ignore all the complexities and just click the run button. And if these kids DO want to continue to learn after this class is over, why not have them use something that's pretty much industry standard so that they don't have to learn a new IDE

Comment: Why not teach your students to use a first-class IDE like eclipse right off the bat? It's a lot easier thank you think, and you can hide all of the advanced stuff! as far as heavyweight, sure eclipse can suck some ram when you have all the features installed but for just raw eclipse+pydev it is really quite lightweight.

Comment: @Andrew: you may want to upload a static copy of the image (like to imgur). Your collabshots link appears to have been ever-so-maturely graffiti'd (which I have cleared).

Answer (score 10):

The Python IDLE has most of these features (never used the debugger before so I don't know how good it is). It's probably the most minimalist Python IDE out there. See http://docs.python.org/library/idle.html for more. IBM also did an overview of IDLE [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-cpyide/#N100A2).

Also, it's already included in the Windows binary (which is what most schools use, at least here), so you won't have to do any special work to get it up and running. It's available for Linux too.

I've never tried [PyScripter](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/) before, but it does seem to offer what you need in an IDE and seems fairly simple. Only con is that it's Windows only.

Comment: IDLE is a royal pain, we used it in our first two courses and it gave too many headaches. Main problem is that it's too unstable.

Comment: @marcog really? I've never had a problem with it, but I'll take your word for it.

Comment: I'd +1 if I wasn't out of votes, IDLE looks exactly like what marcog is looking for.

Comment: @marcog I've looked into a few other IDEs and PyScripter might work for you.

Comment: Sadly, yes. We've tried it in 3 very different environments (all Windows though) and it caused headaches. It's been a while so I can't recall specific problems, unfortunately. But everyone helping at the course will never go back.

Answer (score 9):

JetBrains [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) is terrific.  Not free, though.

Comment: They have a free classroom license, but I doubt that extends to when the kids go home. Perhaps we can crack a deal with them though. Do you know if it supports Python 3 though?

Comment: Is supports whatever version of Python you point it at, as far as I know.  I'm using Python 2.6 here.

Comment: Careful: IntelliJ, which is what PyCharm is built on, uses their own lexing, parsing and semantic analysis framework. They only use the installed Python execution engine for actually *running* the code, for everything else (navigation, refactoring, code completion, code comprehension, syntax highlighting, formatting, ...) they use their own language engine. If that doesn't understand Python 3 syntax and/or semantics, none of that works. (Note: I'm not saying that it doesn't support 3.0, just that the version of the interpreter doesn't necessarily mean anything.)

Comment: Yes, I realize that, but thank you for the clarification, Jorg.

Comment: It does support python 3 iirc however.

Comment: As the lead developer of PyCharm, I'd like to confirm that it does fully support Python 3. It's a full-featured Python IDE, and it does include autocompletion and refactoring features, but you don't have to use them, and all auto-popup suggestions can be turned off.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and the product, yole.  Brilliant stuff.

Comment: I have used pycharm, great product, but i find myself going back to textmate. And why? Cos its clunky and slow, its the reason i prefer not to use large IDE's. So if you want this to work on their home computers, dont think it will work. Granted, PyCharm feels a whole lot snappier then Eclipse or Netbeans, it still manages to kill my machine (MACBOOK 10.6, 2.ghz core 2 duo, 2gb ram!)

Comment: I have to second the use of pycharm here, I've been using it for playing around with python 3 and currently have not come accross issues. Textmate is not cross platform.

Comment: @yole Thanks for the clarification. How does the educational licensing work wrt students working from home? We run a weekend course and would like to let them continue working with the same software from home. We're also looking at starting computer clubs at schools across South Africa. We'd never be able to cover license costs for everyone and most students wouldn't be able to afford it themselves. Would we be able to work something out?

Comment: You should be talking to JetBrains sales.

Comment: There are now free versions of PyCharm available, for anyone looking at this years later...

Comment: Community editions are indeed available for all JetBrains products, but they are not as full-featured as the paid versions.  Cost is minimal; well worth the price.

Answer (score 9):

WingWare's WingIDE is fantastic. I'm not sure if the free Wing 101 has all the features you're looking for, but the personal and professional editions are great little IDEs.

[ http://wingware.com ]

Comment: It may not be free/OS, but it is an impressive IDE and at least deserves consideration. Plus the fact that it's cross platform (Windows, Mac, *nix) is a pretty big plus.

Comment: The nice thing about Wing 101 is that it doesn't include refactoring/autocompletion on purpose.

Answer (score 6):

[Pyscripter](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/) is a nice IDE,has all features you ask for.

Comment: Will have a look. Main problem seems to be that this is Windows-only, which is quite a downside, but I won't write it off.

Comment: SPE IDE - Stani's Python Editor for linux and pyscipter for windows is a good combo.Komodo Edit or Pydev/Eclipse for one IDE krossplatform.

Comment: I've heard negative things about SPE, and I'd much rather stick to one single IDE.

Comment: @marcog: SPE does not support python 3. Anyway do not believe everything you hear, SPE is a **really great** IDE and is cross-platform

Answer (score 6):

[IEP](http://code.google.com/p/iep/) is another lightweight option that should meet all of your requirements.

It has similar goals to [spyder](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/) (which is quite nice, and has been mentioned by a couple of other people) but is a bit more lightweight and *does* support python3.

[image]

It's worth taking a look at anyway...

Comment: The Interactive Help (Req.No.4) is not the best within this IDE, but definitely worth trying.  IMPORTANT: the answer will come from the students not from us. BTW: Dec, 5-11 is CSEDWeek http://www.csedweek.org/ visit, read and help the world to have better programmers

Answer (score 6):

> **Is there a free (preferably open source) IDE you'd recommend that supports Python 3,**

[ActiveState Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide/downloads) is free and [open source](http://www.openkomodo.com/), that also supports Python 3.

> **Cross platform (Windows and Linux)**

Since Komodo is based on the Firefox code base, it runs with native look & feel on Windows, Linux and Mac OS X.

> **Standard features: syntax highlighting, auto-indent, etc.**

[Yup](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/6.0/editor.html).

> **Run button**, rather than console where you have to type "python foo.py".

[Yup](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/6.0/run.html#run_top). Here's [a blog post](http://www.activestate.com/blog/2010/09/writing-pep8-aware-python-code-komodo) of mine demonstrating an use (using pep8) of the Run dialog. There is also a "Toolbox" feature when you can save Run configurations.

> **Contest-aware help** (e.g. when they hover over math.floor() it should give help for the function).

Komodo [does that](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/6.0/editor.html#AutoComplete) (Cmd+hover also works), and [more](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/6.0/hyperlinks.html#hyperlinks_top).

> **Embedded Python shell. Built-in debugger**

These two features are only available in Komodo IDE. ActiveState provides [free licenses](http://www.activestate.com/partners/education-partners) to qualified educational institutions.

> **Useless crud stripped**, e.g. they don't need refactoring tools during an intro class and auto-completion gets in the way of teaching.

Auto-complete and other features can be disabled in Preferences.

> Along the same lines, **it should be lightweight** as some kids will go home to old PCs unable to run beefy IDEs such as Eclipse.

While Komodo is definitely not as beefy as Eclipse, it depends on what you mean by "old PCs". If it can run Firefox 3, then Komodo (which is based on Firefox 3 codebase) too should be able to run on it.

Answer (score 5):

Wing IDE is free for classroom use, including the Wing Pro and Wing Personal product levels.  See https://wingware.com/store/free

Answer (score 4):

Give a try to [Spyderlib](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib) (Spyder is the Scientific PYthon Development EnviRonment)

[Screenshot](http://packages.python.org/spyder/_images/spyder.png)

Comment: spyder does not support python 3

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to go in the opposite direction of Eclipse/Pydev (too big) and recommend [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) (too small).  No, I'm not comfortable even calling it an IDE, but it really nails points 1 and 2, and it is extremely lightweight, suitable for even the wimpiest possible computers that are capable of running Python 3 (or Python 2.3 for that matter).

I think Python is such a nice, small, simple language, if you are only teaching the basics, that you really don't need a full-blown IDE.  I actually find learning an IDE more difficult than learning Python; plus having an IDE sometimes obscures what is part of the language and what is part of the development environment.

***Edit:**  The list of criteria in the original question was edited.  Now SciTE actually meets at least the first three.  At the time of this edit, those are (1) runs on Windows and Linux, (2) has typical programming editor features like syntax highlighting and so forth, (3) has a button to execute the script.*

Answer (score 3):

It's Windows only, but the PythonWin IDE that comes with Mark Hammond's pywin32 package meets all your requirements including support for Python 3.1. Download it at: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/

Comment: Just curious why this was down voted. PythonWin does everything IDLE does and the OP said "if Windows-only is a winner I'll take it,"

Comment: Probably because it doesn't look like an IDE from the download page, and there are no screens.

Answer (score 3):

I am teaching myself python, and atm, GEANY works best for me.

Geany is a text editor using the GTK2 toolkit with basic features of an integrated development environment. It was developed to provide a small and fast IDE, which has only a few dependencies from other packages. It supports many filetypes and has some nice features.

You can download it [here](http://www.geany.org/)

Comment: To me Geany is just an editor. No different in any way from any other editor from Python perspective. 4,5,6 probably won't apply, so -1.

Answer (score 0):

I have been hearing a lot of praises about Aptana Studio recently ( made by the coders of PyDev ).
http://aptana.com/products/studio3/download
Personally using Eclipse + PyDev and really recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

[PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) is awesome. Looks good, perform nicely and has now a Free Community Edition!