# IDE to teach children python?

Tags: python, ide, collaboration

I am looking for an lightweight IDE (lightweight enough to run on a raspberry pi_ similar to the ones described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292909/python-3-ide-for-teaching) with collaborative support similar to Google Docs, Gobby, Cloud 9, Codiad, etc., so that I can help to teach programming.

It seems that there are many collaborative editors, and many very nice IDE's, however there are very few collaborative IDE's, with debugging support and a run button.

Personally, I use vim, with the excellent plugin CoVim if I want to edit collaboratively, however vim is not particularly user friendly.

Open source is a huge plus, though not strictly necessary. Cross-platform support, including linux, is a must (and not just through x11 and gtk+ on mac -- many applications say they are available on mac but in truth you have to install half a linux distro if you want them to work). If it supports vim bindings I would be very happy, but this is completely not necessary.

A whole educational IDE, with classroom support and assignment submission would be a very useful thing to have, now that I come to think of it. Just a side-thought.

Answer (score 3):

I would recomend:

http://www.learpython.org/

http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/thinkcspy/
or:

http://codenode.org/

http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/htmlnotebook.html

They are not IDE's, but there are great collaboration tools.

If you want a lightweight IDE, have you considered [geany](http://geany.org/) ?

For collaboration:

See [GOBBY](http://gobby.0x539.de/trac/), or [GEDIT-COLLABORATION](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gedit-collaboration/) (the former seems quite inactive). And I am not sure how lightweight they are ...

Comment: These all look like great tools for the purpose they were intended for, and I have considered geany. However again, there are many IDE's that are not collaborative, and many collaborative tools that are not IDE's. This question was asked for one that was both.

Comment: I've found cloud9, which fits this perfectly